# How can i prevent my rooted app to be disabled by default user?

Tags: android, system, root

I'm building an enterprise application that needs to get some information about the employees' rooted phones to do corporate management.
This application cannot be disabled and if to be possible cannot be stopped.

[image]

Is possible to put my app as Google Play Services ?

Thanks ....

Comment: Who rooted the devices? Did the employees root it? Or did your IT department do it? Does everyone have the same device? If they do, then it may be worth creating your own custom corporate rom.

Comment: Well, i'm the responsible by this part. Create a ROM , it's an impossible choice now. I really need to do this application not disable. Is there any other way?